# spark Dataset to java object mapping field with underscore

Tags: java, apache-spark

Dataset in spark has a column with name `no_of_items`. In the corresponding Java Model (Product) I have a column name as `noOfItems`. Now when I convert Dataset to Dataset using the following code

```
df.as(Encoders.bean(Product.class));
```

It throws the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`noOfItems`' given input columns: [category, sub_category, no_of_items];
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Before converting `df` to `dataset`, rename the column,

```
df.withColumnRenamed("no_of_items", "noOfItems").as(Encoders.bean(Product.class));
```